# A-Frame / THREE.js, Simplify modifier is not defined Error

Tags: three.js, aframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Z87.png)

How can I defin new SimplifyModifier on A-frame ?

Uncaught ReferenceError: SimplifyModifier is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimplifyModifier` is no part of the `three.js` core.

Similar to other extensions like loaders, controls or post-processing passes, you have to import modifiers from the examples directory. I suggest you study how the official example handles the ES6 import:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_simplifier

Depending on your app structure, you probably want to import the globals script version instead from the `examples/js` directory.

Comment: Yes I want to import globals script version not super-three but I don't now how can do that. I am trying do similar example on a-frame